# MouseListener error pertaining to VariableDeclaratorId expected

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouselistener, variable-declaration

I'm doing a simple Java GUI application using Swing and I'm trying to get my JList to respond to double-clicks via the MouseListener class. My code pertaining to it is as follows:

```
MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter(itemList) {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
            int index = itemList.locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());
            System.out.println(index);
        }
    }
};
itemList.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
}
```

However, on the period after itemList I get an error saying "Syntax error on tokens, misplaced constructs" and on the (mouseListener) I see a "Syntax error on token mouseListener, VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token.  The problem is that I see this exact same code being the simple way to implement MouseListeners but I seem to not be able to find anyone else who have seen this problem before. Could anyone offer insight as to why this problem is persisting?

Answer (score 1):

[`MouseAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) only has a no-args contructor.

```
MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter(){

    //override the methods

};
```

Comment: I removed the argument from the constructor but the same error still persists.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?